# Running a Python script on features in Oracle SDE database

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, sdelayer

I am running a Python script on data in an Oracle ArcSDE database. My script works exactly as it should locally, but I start getting empty lists as soon as I run it in ArcSDE. Without going into too much detail I have to run it on the ArcSDE feature classes. `ListFields` keeps producing empty lists when it should be populated with the desired fields.

Why is that happening?
Discovered that I am using Python 3 where I need to be using Python 2.7 for our specific version(?) of Oracle SDE!

```
# Modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import csv

# Environemts
env.overwriteOutput = True
env.qualifiedFieldNames = True
env.transferDomains = True
sdeconn = arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management(r'C:\sdeconn', 'sdeconntest.sde', 'ORACLE', 'instance', 'DATABASE_AUTH', 'username', 'password', 'SAVE_USERNAME')
env.workspace = sdeconn


# Null value error reporting function
def null_error_report(fc):
    desc = arcpy.da.Describe(fc)
    fcname = desc['baseName']
    fieldlist = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
    print(fieldlist)
    null_check = 'DEPT_RESP IS NULL'
    fc_nulls = []

    # Included fields
    oid = 'OBJECTID'
    modby = 'MODIFIED_BY'

    # Mandatory fields
    stnum = 'STREET_NUMBER'
    stname = 'STREET_NAME'
    deptresp = 'DEPT_RESP'

    # Pole mandatory
    subtypecd = 'SUBTYPECD'
    circuits = 'CIRCUITS'

    # Light mandatory
    lightsource = 'LIGHT_SOURCE'
    numlights = 'NUM_LIGHTS'
    poleoid = 'POLE_OBJECTID'
    transoid = 'XMISN_OBJECTID'
    lightuse = 'LIGHT_USAGE'

    print('Running NULL values error report for {}...'.format(fcname))

    # Light report
    if stnum in fieldlist and stname in fieldlist and lightsource in fieldlist and numlights in fieldlist and poleoid in fieldlist \
            and transoid in fieldlist and lightuse in fieldlist and deptresp in fieldlist:
        print('Finding nulls in {} feature class'.format(fcname))
        fields = [oid, stnum, stname, lightsource, numlights, poleoid, transoid, lightuse, deptresp, modby]
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields, null_check) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                fc_nulls.append(row)
        if bool(fc_nulls):
            with open(r'C:\error_reports\{}_errorreport.csv.'.format(fcname), 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                writer.writerow(fields)
                writer.writerows(fc_nulls)
            print('Error report for {} complete'.format(fcname))
        else:
            print('No null values for {}'.format(fcname))

    # Pole report
    elif stnum in fieldlist and stname in fieldlist and subtypecd in fieldlist and circuits in fieldlist and deptresp in fieldlist:
        print('Finding nulls in {} feature class'.format(fcname))
        fields = [oid, stnum, stname, subtypecd, circuits, deptresp, modby]
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields, null_check) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                fc_nulls.append(row)
        if bool(fc_nulls):
            with open(r'C:\error_reports\{}_errorreport.csv.'.format(fcname), 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                writer.writerow(fields)
                writer.writerows(fc_nulls)
            print('Error report for {} complete'.format(fcname))
        else:
            print('No null values for {}'.format(fcname))

    # Mandatory standard report
    elif stnum in fieldlist and stname in fieldlist and deptresp in fieldlist:
        print('Finding nulls in {} feature class'.format(fcname))
        fields = [oid, stnum, stname, deptresp, modby]
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields, null_check) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                fc_nulls.append(row)
        if bool(fc_nulls):
            with open(r'C:\error_reports\{}_errorreport.csv.'.format(fcname), 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                writer.writerow(fields)
                writer.writerows(fc_nulls)
            print('Error report for {} complete'.format(fcname))
        else:
            print('No null values for {}'.format(fcname))

    # Lines loop
    elif deptresp in fieldlist:
        print('Finding nulls in {} feature class'.format(fcname))
        fields = [oid, deptresp, modby]
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields, null_check) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                fc_nulls.append(row)
        if bool(fc_nulls):
            with open(r'C:\error_reports\{}_errorreport.csv.'.format(fcname), 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                writer.writerow(fields)
                writer.writerows(fc_nulls)
            print('Error report for {} complete'.format(fcname))
        else:
            print('No null values for {}'.format(fcname))

# Features to run report on 
capbank = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Network_Features\ELECOWNER.CapacitorBank'
dpd = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Network_Features\ELECOWNER.DynamicProtDevice'
fusebank = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Network_Features\ELECOWNER.FuseBank'
miscnetft = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Network_Features\ELECOWNER.MiscNetworkFeature'
primeter = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Network_Features\ELECOWNER.PrimaryMeter'
regbank = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Network_Features\ELECOWNER.RegulatorBank'
switchbank = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Network_Features\ELECOWNER.SwitchBank'
transbank = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Network_Features\ELECOWNER.TransformerBank'
distgen = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Structures\ELECOWNER.DistributionGeneration'
prioh = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Network_Features\ELECOWNER.PrimaryOHLine'
priug = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Network_Features\ELECOWNER.PrimaryUGLine'
secoh = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Network_Features\ELECOWNER.SecondaryOHLine'
secug = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Network_Features\ELECOWNER.SecondaryUGLine'
seccon = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Network_Features\ELECOWNER.SecondaryConnections'
jua = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Structures\ELECOWNER.JUA'
pole = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Structures\ELECOWNER.Pole'
light = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Structures\ELECOWNER.Light'
riser = r'C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde\ELECOWNER.Electric_Structures\ELECOWNER.Riser'
priftssde = [capbank, dpd, fusebank, miscnetft, primeter, regbank, switchbank, transbank, distgen, prioh, priug, secoh, secug, seccon, jua, pole, light, riser]

for sdeft in priftssde:
    null_error_report(sdeft)
```

Comment: Is your edit of `Discovered that I am using python 3 where I need to be using python 2.7 for our specific version(?) of Oracle SDE!` the "answer"? If so, please don't add the answer to the question. You can do a self-answer

Comment: Can you open C:\sdeconn\gisweb.sde in Pro? (assuming you are using Pro as your client.

Comment: The legacy 32-bit ArcGIS Desktop apps use Python 2.7, but ArcGIS Pro uses Python 3.x. You can't force either to use the other.